# Date format returning Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have the following which creates an array of dates between 'start' and 'end' dates.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('U', $start);
$to   = Carbon::createFromFormat('U', $end);

$dates = [];
for ($date = $from; $date->lte($to); $date->addDay()) {
    $dates[] = $date->format('d-m-y');
}
```

I need to format the output of the dates to be in the format 04 October 2020.  It is currently returning error 'Call to a member function format() on string' when I try and convert the date.

```
foreach ($dates as $date) :
  echo $date;
endforeach;
```

I needed the date to be set initially to d-m-y format for this comparision:

```
foreach ($events as $event) :
    if (date('d-m-y', $event->start) === $date) : 
        .....further processing
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: `$dates[] = $date->format('d-m-y');` Do you really need to store them as strings, or can you store them as Carbon entities and then format them as you need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range of `Carbon` instance is typically handled with `CarbonPeriod`:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$dates = Carbon::parse('@' . $start)->daysUntil('@' . $end);
```

Display:

```
foreach ($dates as $date) :
    echo $date->format('d F Y');
endforeach;
```

Compare:

```
foreach ($events as $event) :
    if ($event->start->isSameDay($date)) : 
        .....further processing
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks, using isSameDay is a better solution